# Guardar Uid de Un usuario de FireBase

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas, tengo  una aplicacion donde envio unos datos y cuando envio los datos quiero que me guarde con el Envio el Uid del usuario que esta ahora mismo conectado.

El metodo que tengo es este

```
private void saveInformation()
{
    //initializing firebase authentication object
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //getting current user
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //Getting values from database
    String aviso = aviso1.getText().toString().trim();
    String descripcion = textDes.getText().toString().trim();
    String ubicacion = textubi.getText().toString().trim();
    //La linea que esta mal
    Usuario usuario = user.getUid();

    //Creamos un objeto para guardar la informacion
    Aviso avisoInformation = new Aviso(aviso,descripcion,ubicacion,usuario);

    databaseReference.child("Aviso").push().setValue(avisoInformation);

    //displaying a success toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "Guardando informacion del aviso, espera...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Tengo un constructor Con sus 3 Strings y Usuario usuario. Pero ahora para intentar guardar el Uid(Es un String) como lo podria guardar o que puedo hacer??

Si necesitais alguna parte mas del codigo avisar.

Gracias

//VerAvisos

```
public class VerAviso extends MenuAvisos
{

    List<Aviso> avisos;
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.veraviso);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final ArrayAdapter<Aviso> adapter;

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Aviso>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                avisos.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                        dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Aviso aviso2 = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                    avisos.add(aviso2);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Enhorabuena , alguien preguntando sobre firebase, en un momento te dejo mi respuesta.

Comment: Obtener el uid ya lo sabes realizar, la pregunta es que recibe el objeto Aviso como usuario, un String o un Objeto usuario con la propiedad usuario :  new Aviso(aviso,descripcion,ubicacion,usuario);???

Comment: @Jorgesys hay muchas cosas que no se saben, la pregunta en si, ya fue respondida, creo que estamos siendo muy amables xD.

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo todo solucionado, muchisimas gracias @EduardoRicardez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muy bien,
Para obtener el UID del usuario actual pones esta linea al comienzo

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Estas declarando al usuario que sera la instancia del usuario actual.

Y listo luego lo utilizas para lo que gustes ¿Te pongo ejemplos? Alli te va.

```
    btnAgregarEvento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Llenado del objeto evento con los respectivos EditText
                    evento.setNombre(etNombreEvento.getText().toString());
                    evento.setLugar(etLugarEvento.getText().toString());

                    //Mandar evento a Firebase
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//Digo la ubicacion de lo que voy a guardar , por ejemplo,en nodo hijo evento del nodo hijo UID del usuario dentro del nodo usuario 
                    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("utilisateur").child(user.getUid()).child("evenement");
//Ya dentro de la ubicacion guardo todo.
                    Evento evento2= new Evento(evento.getNombre(),evento.getLugar());
                    myRef.push().setValue(evento2);

                }
            });
```

Al final lo que guardaste quedaria asi en la base de datos

```
Usuarios
       -- UID(De cada cliente)
                              --Evento (El Evento creado que tiene cada cliente)
                                    --EventoKey
                                        -- (Valores dentro del evento, como nombre,lugar, etc ) 
                                    --EventoKey
                                        -- (Valores dentro del evento, como nombre,lugar, etc ) 
                                    --EventoKey
                                        -- (Valores dentro del evento, como nombre,lugar, etc ) 
                                    --EventoKey
                                        -- (Valores dentro del evento, como nombre,lugar, etc )
```

Etc

Pero ahora te preguntaras :

-Oh Eduardo , ¿Pero luego como muestro los respectivos datos ( eventos en el ejemplo) de cada usuario?

Y yo te respondere:
-No temas, aqui tienes un ejemplo de como obtener los datos :

```
database.getReference("utilisateur").child(user.getUid()).child("evenement").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            eventos.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

               Evento evento2 = snapshot.getValue(Evento.class);
                eventos.add(evento2);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Como podras ver, solo agregar el nodo del usuario a la consulta . 
Espero te sirva, aunque ya pasaron 3 horas , le sirva a los futuros que tengan tu misma duda.

Cualquier otra duda sobre Firebase no dude en postearlo y sera respondido.
Bon courage.

Comment: Para guardar los datos me funciona perfectamente, ahora para mostrarlos mas o menos lo entiendo como funciona, pero quiero mostrar la información en otra actividad no en la misma. Como seria? eventos de donde sale?

Gracias!

Comment: Entonces estas verde en Firebase , ese es otro tema , que a merita otro post , pero tratare de explicarte por aqui :

@CristianPrietoBeltran Estamos de acuerdo que database.getReference es para ubicarte en alguna parte de tu base de datos , es como la dirección , asi que podras usarla en cualquier Activity y traeras los datos que se te antojen, ahora , hay una pregunta que hacerte ¿Donde quieres mostrar los datos? En un RecyclerView? , Una Variable? , etc ,etc .

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran Toda la información esta en el snapshot , tomas el valor utilizando el metodo .getValue(), lo que yo estoy haciendo en el codigo de ejemplo , es pasar todos los datos de la referencia a un Objeto , El Objeto Evento.class , esa clase con getters y setters y un constructor,en ese objeto tengo las variables llamadas tal cual, exactamente igual como estan en la base de datos , asi que al hacer snapshot.getValue(Evento.class) estoy llenando el objeto con todos los valores y despues agrego el objeto a una lista de objetos List<Evento>... para despues pasarselo al Adapter.

Comment: ¿Se entiende? Si necesitas saber mas , por favor, hacer una pregunta especifica de lo siguiente que quieres lograr en una pregunta nueva.
Y si te funcionó no olvides darle a la palomita que se ponga verde. n_n

Comment: Para mostrarlos tenia pensado en unas Variables como unos TextView, pero si es mejor hacerlo en una Lista o RecyclerView pues no importa, mientras los muestre da igual como. El getReference lo tengo claro, que yo me ubico en mi BBDD desde ("Aviso"). Igual que tengo mi Aviso.class con todos sus getters i setters y su constructor igual que en  mi Firebase. Ahora he creado la lista para añadirlo como dices, pero me falta por entender mejor lo del Adapter, como seria? Que lo he mirado pero no se como es, te pongo el Codigo arriba mejor @EduardoRicardez

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran Ya lo reviso.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el método `.getUid()` obtiene un String con el id de usuario,

> **getUid()** : Devuelve un identificador de usuario especificado por el proveedor de autenticación.

por lo tanto, en lugar de guardarlo en un objeto Usuario simplemente guárdalo en una variable tipo `String`:

```
//Usuario usuario = user.getUid();
  String usuario = user.getUid();
```

pero esto es si tu objeto `Aviso` recibe el usuario como `String`:

```
 //Creamos un objeto para guardar la informacion
 Aviso avisoInformation = new Aviso(aviso,descripcion,ubicacion,usuario);
```

Si tu objeto `Aviso` recibe un objeto usuario, puedes optar por crear el objeto y agregarle la propiedad usuario:

```
//Instancia objeto usuario.
 Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
//Agrega Uid al objeto usuario. 
usuario.setUsuario(user.getUid());
```